# How to manage Mysql image response in gwt?

Tags: java, mysql, image, gwt, base64

I got a problem, I can't display an image from my Database in GWT, even when I proved and I could save the image in my computer. Here is the code:

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8096];
        int len = 0;

        while ( (len = in.read( bytes ))> 0 )
        {
            if(!fichero.exists())
            {
                out.write( bytes, 0, len );
            }
        }

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        //byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);

        String base64 = Base64Utils.toBase64(bytes); 
        //base64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+base64;
        base64 = "data:image/gif;base64,"+base64;
        return base64;

        }
        else
        {
            return "http://cracktouch.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Run-Like-Hell-Deluxe.png";
        }
```

This code is in the class GreetingServiceImpl.
"in" is an Inputstream with the image which is correct because I could save the image in my computer, but I can't  display it in GWT when I use the string base64 like this:
Image image = new Image(base64);
contenido.add(image);
Any suggestion?

Comment: Try providing more info to get a better answer.Are you seeing any error messages? "byte" is the image, right? What is out (you are writing the image unencoded into out and then you encode the image)? That looks odd.

Answer (score 1):

The `bytes` array is fixed size and is bigger then the image data - so there are some unused 0s at the end.

Call to `Base64Utils.toBase64(bytes)` converts the whole array including unused data to string.

Either trim the array or use a Base64 implementation where you can specify size of input data.